# Better PSMTabBarControl / Cocoa Tabs

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, tabs

I want to unify multiple windows from my OS X-Application into a Tab-View, just like Safari, Espresso, Finder, CodeRunner… I found PSMTabBarControl which does the job, but the look and feel are quite different from the other applications I saw.

[Comparison (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuNcM.png)

Then I found out, that those applications had always the same name for the resources used for the Tabs.

[Screenshot of the recourses from CodeRunner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okYKg.png)

Could I just «steal» those images and use them in my own application with PSMTabBarControl or is there another way to get a more native look (not like the PSMTabBarControl default or Chromium Tabs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try [MMTabBarView](http://mimo42.github.io/MMTabBarView/).

> MMTabBarView is a modernized and view based re-write of PSMTabBarControl.

Answer (score 1):

I release a open source TabbarView controls for OS X and Cocoa recently, you may want to have a look at it [here](https://github.com/aaron-elkins/ENTabBarView).